# delphi datasnap 2010 from server to client file transfer

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datasnap

Have anyone tried to transfer file from Server to Client? or Transferring XML from Server to Client? Can anyone a running code for this?

thanks and best regards,

btw, how could I post an answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can post an answer to *this* question by clicking the big "answer your question" button at the bottom of the page and typing your answer. To answer someone else's question, simply type your answer into the text box below the "your answer" heading. For *other people* to answer this question, I think you're going to have to provide more details about what you're really having trouble with. Use the "edit" link below your question and then describe your circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use streams](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jimtierney/2009/04/06/31461) to transfer files. XML is a text file, and can be transferred using strings as well.